# setting facebook app as home page

Tags: facebook

I'm wondering how to set an app/iframe as the home page on a facebook brand page similar to how coca cola have achieved this - http://www.facebook.com/cocacola

I'm certain this this not something I can achieve through code and I've had a look through the facebook developer documentation for how to this using the facebook interface.

It's a maze of unhelpfulness.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it's a reasonable question for facebook app devs. If I asked a simple, even downright stupid, question about the Visual Studio interface I doubt I'd be downvoted. Depressing as it may be, the Facebook interface is now another tool programmers may have to learn. Rant Over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably have there is a Facebook application with a configured tab page.  As the owner or admin of a page you can add whatever tabs you want, and even make them the default tab for visitors who are not already fans or admins of your page.

So here's how to do it:

1. Create yourself a Facebook application, and make sure to set up a version with a max width of 520px.
2. In your application settings configure the tab page settings to point at the narrow version of your app.
3. Go to the Application's profile page, and from the links on the side select 'Add to my page'., select the page you want to add the app to.
4. In your page settings, set the default tab to the App tab you just added.

Comment: it should be noted this works only for non-fans. fans always get the wall.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have already made my application and set it up as a tab on the page (so it appears in the left hand bar) I've just tried to do step 4 of your instructions - I've gone to my page (www.facebook.com/myclientsbrandpage)  Clicked the "edit page" button in the top right, then changed the "Default Landing Tab" to be my app tab. It's still not working. Do you think this could take some time to update? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry - as per  Rufinus's comment I couldn't see it. As I am and admin I am automatically a fan.

Comment: @Rufinus: yep, I missed that out. good spot.